# Time mismatched on servers - Two factor authentication in php

Tags: php, two-factor-authentication

I've created two-factor authentication in PHP using google authenticator. It works well on my localhost, but on my website the generated code was mismatched. I found this is a time configuration issue. assist me to set up time on two-factor.

```
public function verifyCode($secret, $code, $discrepancy = 1, $currentTimeSlice = null)
{
    if ($currentTimeSlice === null) {
        $currentTimeSlice = floor(time() / 30);
    }

    for ($i = -$discrepancy; $i <= $discrepancy; $i++) {
        $calculatedCode = $this->getCode($secret, $currentTimeSlice + $i);
        if ($calculatedCode == $code ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is a time drift on the web server. Make sure the time on the web server is correct and precise (UTC).